# TapJoy rotates all my UIViewContollers used inside the game

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, screen-rotation, tapjoy

I use TapJoy SDK in my an OpenGL based game (based on [Maze+](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/maze+/id457617044?mt=8) code)

when i use the following code in the App Delegate to show full screen ads

```
[TapjoyConnect showFeaturedAppFullScreenAd];
```

or even use the following code in the more games view to show more games

```
[TapjoyConnect showOffersWithViewController:self withInternalNavBar:NO];
```

i got all my View controllers (like more games view and news view) rotated see the screen shot

[image]

do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this line should fix the problem.

[vc.view setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];

It should come before this:

vc.view.frame = view.frame;

[view addSubview:vc.view];